# Increase amount in % SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, percentage

```
select sr.id,sr.increasedamount,sr.newsalary
    from revision sr
    inner join vwemp vw on vw.id=sr.id

id      increasedamount newsalary   
15691   14600           80000   
12500   2236            26000   
12501   1969            25500   
1252    1982            25000
```

Now in this I want % to display how much % increase  like in first record amount is 14600
so I want to display 14% increase in new column

```
id      increasedamount newsalary    increment in %
15691   14600           80000   
12500   2236            26000   
12501   1969            25500   
1252    1982            25000
```

Comment: how do  you calculate  increment in % ?

Comment: i already have increment amount in value now i want to just display in % .

Comment: Old salary is 80000-14600 = 65400, so it should be 22% in new column correct ?

Comment: yes i think so @MitBhatt

Comment: there is cofusion.. when i multiply 65400 * 22 % =14388 .. this shows 14388 where i want 80,000 so how this could be 22%?

Comment: why down -1?????????/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sr.id,sr.increasedamount,sr.newsalary,
CASE WHEN sr.newsalary-sr.increasedamount=0 THEN 0 
ELSE (sr.increasedamount)*(100/CONVERT(decimal,(sr.newsalary-sr.increasedamount))) END as 'incrementinpercentage'
from revision sr
inner join vwemp vw on vw.id=sr.id
```

Comment: this shows error .. Divide by zero error encountered

Comment: this shows 0 against each id.. have you test your query ?

Comment: I have retested and updated my query... I missed it earlier

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this

```
SELECTC id,
        increasedamount,
        newsalary,
        ((increasedamount*1.0)/(newsalary-increasedamount))*100 
FROM revision
```

Comment: there is cofusion.. when i multiply 65400 * 22 % =14388 .. this shows 14388 where i want 80,000 so how this could be 22%?

Comment: @cool user: You need to change operator and add braces, (65400 + 22%) will give you 79,788. If you want exact 80,000 then you need to consider all the decimals and that also in some cases will not give you exact number(Ex. (5/3) kind of number).

Comment: which operator i need to change

Comment: Replace * with +, copy and paste (65400 + 22%) in calc

Comment: means for 80,000 increase amount is 14600 so here  65400 is old salary

80,000-14600=65400

so on 65400 amount 14600 is increase to become 80,000 ..

so i want to display that 14600 in % . means what percent % is increase on 65400 to become 80,000

Comment: Just removed Cast Function from Select, this will give exact percentage Amount, check updated

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get an amount that is 22% high then your existing amount, just multiply it by 1.22. If you need it rounded to a specific value, use the round function on the result to get to the desired amount of zeros. round(salary, -2) will round to the nearest hundred.  For example, if old_salary is $100 for ID = 1, the below would result in 1, $122, $22

```
select sr.id, (OLD_SALARY*1.22) NewSALARY, (OLD_SALARY*1.22 -OLD_SALARY)Increasedamount from table
```

If you just want it to look like 22% in your result instead of .22, you will need to do something like 
    cast(Increment*100 as varchar)+ '%'

Answer (score 0):

```
Below query will give you expected results

declare @userData TABLE(id int,increasedamount int,newsalary int)
insert into @userData values(15691,14600,80000)
insert into @userData values(12500,2236,26000)
insert into @userData values(12501,1969,25500)
insert into @userData values(1252,1982,25000)

select id,increasedamount,newsalary,(case when previousSalary > 0 then (increasedamount *100/previousSalary) else 0 end) incrementPercentage
from (select id,increasedamount,newsalary,(newsalary - increasedamount) previousSalary from @userData) as t
```

Comment: means for 80,000 increase amount is 14600 so here  65400 is old salary

80,000-14600=65400

so on 65400 amount 14600 is increase to become 80,000 ..

so i want to display that 14600 in % . means what percent % is increase on 65400 to become 80,000

Comment: yes for 15691 output is .. increasedamount=14600 newsalary=80000 incrementpercentage=22

Comment: yes if you will run my query snippet you will get the expected output

Comment: i run your query and this is the ouptut.. increasedamount=14600 newsalary=80000 incrementpercentage=22

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135369/discussion-between-chintan-udeshi-and-cool-user).